# Pandas identify # of items which generate 80 of sales

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with for each country, list of product and the relevant sales
I need to identify for each country how many are # of top sales items of which cumulative sales represent 80% of the total sales for all the items in each country.

E.g.

```
Cnt Product, units
Italy apple 500
Italy beer 1500
Italy bread 2000
Italy orange 3000
Italy butter 3000
```

Expected results

```
Italy 3
```

(Total units are 10.000 and the sales of the top 3 product - Butter, Orange, Bread, is 8.000 which is the 80% of total)

Answer (score 2):

Try define a function and apply on groupby:

```
def get_sale(x, pct=0.8):

    thresh = 0.8 * x.sum()

    # sort values descendingly for top salse
    x=x.sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    # store indices of those with cumsum pass threshold
    sale_pass_thresh = x.index[x.cumsum().ge(thresh)]

    return sale_pass_thresh[0] + 1

df.groupby('Cnt').units.apply(get_sale)
```

Output:

```
Cnt
Italy    3
Name: units, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It’s a series, not data frame. You can get a data frame by `outSeries.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

Need play a little bit logic here

```
df=df.sort_values('units',ascending=False)
g=df.groupby('Cnt').units
s=(g.cumsum()>=g.transform('sum')*0.8).groupby(df.Cnt).sum()
df.groupby('Cnt').size()-s+1
Out[710]: 
Cnt
Italy    3.0
dtype: float64
```